# How to create a PDF database diagram in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, pdf, erd

I have a relatively small database that I would like to generate a diagram for and then create a pdf of that diagram.  I have the diagram created in SQL Server (all tables would fit on one page of a pdf document) but cannot figure out how to export it to a document.  Is this possible?  The only option I've found is to copy it to the clipboard and then paste it into a Word Document but the quality isn't very good.

Comment: This isn't really on-topic.  It's not a programming question, unless you want to know how to write a program that can do this.  That said, I agree with @dcp's answer.  CutePdf is very convenient for this type of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not used it myself but [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) appears to be able to draw an ERD using Graphviz, which can be output into ps2 (among many other formats) and converted to PDF.

Answer (score 32):

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2014:

1. Right click diagram area
2. On the menu bar select "Database Diagram" >> "Copy diagram to Clipboard"
3. Open MS Word and paste it

Comment: Unfortunately for huge databases that won't work properly. The image will be tiny and you're not able to read anything

Answer (score 20):

For better quality
After generating the diagram in sql server management studio

Go to **File -> page setup**

Set print Scale into 10 or lower.
Select paper size into tabloid
Set Orientation into Landscape
Set printer name microsoft print to pdf
After that press ok
[image]

And go back to generated diagram
Right click and select view page break

[image]

Now you can drag and drop each tables inside the page you want.

After that click on **File ->print**
Select Microsoft print to PDF and hit **print** button.

You will get a PDF of ER diagram

Answer (score 11):

To display your diagram in PDF format, follow the below steps:

- Click anywhere in the diagram area
- Right click -> Copy to clipboard
- Paste it in paint window
- Save it as a png image
- Open browser and search for png to pdf converter online tool
- Convert it to pdf

Comment: for pdf converter as a tool, I recommend Foxit Reader.
Blank Page --> From File (on Home tab) and add the png file you've just saved. The conversion will be done in seconds.

Comment: You can also just print it as a PDF document with "Microsoft Print to PDF" build in printer-option.

Comment: wow this is awesome. I can save it as one big png image.

Answer (score 6):

Simply print it as PDF or as save as PDF.

**Step 1:** Right click on the diagram area and **SELECT ALL**

Or

select all tables one by one holding shift

**File ---> Print ----> Adobe PDF / Microsoft to PDF ---> Print Button**

Comment: It does work and I don't have any extension. What are you talking about @Rahatur

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Right click on the diagram area and `SELECT ALL`

Step 2: File->Print -> chose default: `Microsoft XPS Document Writer`

Step 3: created `*.oxps` file convert to `PDF` on `http://oxpstopdf.com/`

Answer (score 2):

My favorite tool for this type of thing is [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/). You can just print the diagram, but then you can pick the CutePDF writer from the printer dialog, and it'll print it to a PDF (you can choose the file you want it printed to).

Answer (score 0):

Print to OneNote, then export as PDF.