# Export SQL Server Database Diagram

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way I can export a SQL Server database diagram? I tried taking a screenshot of the structure but there's that many tables that if I zoom to 100% view nothing can be read.

Comment: You can export to .pdf (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036284/how-to-create-a-pdf-database-diagram-in-sql-server)

That can help you ?

Comment: That would. Might be completely missing something but how do I do that?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running that it doesn't have Microsoft Print to PDF as an option in the print dialog?

Comment: Sorry, never even thought of that. Got it exported. It looks awful. Is there any tool or format where that's better suited for sharing without me having to manually draw the diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MSSMS I went to File, then Page Setup and set the print scale to 20%. Then I printed the file to pdf.

Comment: Welcome.
Good answer and question about this topic is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036284/how-to-create-a-pdf-database-diagram-in-sql-server please read about how to answer question in help center for give best feedback : https://stackoverflow.com/help